# How to make a real XLS file on asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have this code to extract a table to computer in a .xls file:

```
// I have a string which contains HTML table codes, named as excelTable

HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("Attachment;Filename=file.xls", ));
response.Buffer = true;
response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
response.Write(excelTable);
response.End();
```

And I have seen that this is not a real .xls file. I can open it in Notepad and see my standart html table codes.

Now I understand that defining `ContentType` is not enough. So what else can I do to generate a pure .xls or .xlsx file? Or Should I certainly use Excel Libraries like OpenXML, Interop, etc. ?

Comment: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Actual* XLS/XLSX data must be sent back - that is, data generated with a library (e.g [EEPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)) or other suitable source.

This common hack/approach works because Excel "knows how to read HTML". It *doesn't* actually turn the HTML into XSL/XLSX, although it can be saved as *new* spreadsheet once loaded by Excel.

Changing the content type will have no effect on the *data*, and instead will effectively stop this approach from working: the content type is used for associating the program (i.e. Excel) which will be used to open/read the data.

So yes: to generate a *real* XLS/XLSX document, use a library.